# Flutter dismiss selected dialog with Getx

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

I am using flutter for quite some time and recently use Get to implement state management.
I am facing a problem when opening a loading dialog 1st and then message dialog. Then I want to dismiss the loading dialog, but the message dialog is the one that keep dismiss.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';

class HomeController extends GetxController {

  Future<void> openAndCloseLoadingDialog() async {
    showDialog(
      context: Get.overlayContext,
      barrierDismissible: false,
      builder: (_) => WillPopScope(
        onWillPop: () async => false,
        child: Center(
          child: SizedBox(
            width: 60,
            height: 60,
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(
              strokeWidth: 10,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );

    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 3));

    Get.dialog(
      AlertDialog(
        title: Text("This should not be closed automatically"),
        content: Text("This should not be closed automatically"),
        actions: <Widget>[
          FlatButton(
            child: Text("CLOSE"),
            onPressed: () {
              Get.back();
            },
          )
        ],
      ),
      barrierDismissible: false,
    );

    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 3));

    Navigator.of(Get.overlayContext).pop();
  }
}
```

The above code dismisses the 2nd dialog, not the 1st dialog which what I want.
Can anyone give advice on this matter.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The reason why the `AlertDialog` is being dismissed instead of `CircularProgressIndicator` is because `AlertDialog` is on the top of the stack. What you can do here is to call `Navigator.of(Get.overlayContext).pop();` to dismiss `CircularProgressIndicator` prior to displaying the `AlertDialog`.

[image: Demo]

Sample code based from the snippets provided.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GetMaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;
  final HomeController c = Get.put(HomeController());

  void _incrementCounter() {
    c.openAndCloseLoadingDialog();
    // setState(() {
    //   _counter++;
    // });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class HomeController extends GetxController {

  Future<void> openAndCloseLoadingDialog() async {
    showDialog(
      context: Get.overlayContext,
      barrierDismissible: false,
      builder: (_) => WillPopScope(
        onWillPop: () async => false,
        child: Center(
          child: SizedBox(
            width: 60,
            height: 60,
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(
              strokeWidth: 10,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );

    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 3));
    // Dismiss CircularProgressIndicator
    Navigator.of(Get.overlayContext).pop();

    Get.dialog(
      AlertDialog(
        title: Text("This should not be closed automatically"),
        content: Text("This should not be closed automatically"),
        actions: <Widget>[
          FlatButton(
            child: Text("CLOSE"),
            onPressed: () {
              Get.back();
            },
          )
        ],
      ),
      barrierDismissible: false,
    );

    // await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 3));
    // Navigator.of(Get.overlayContext).pop();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try to use `closeOverlays` param this way :

```
Get.back(closeOverlays: true);
```

Comment: This will also close the current screen.

Answer (score 0):

I use it with `bottomSheet()`, but it will also work fine with `Dialog`. Just add an argument to `Get.back(closeOverlays: true)`:

```
Get.bottomSheet(
  WillPopScope(
    onWillPop: () async {
      Get.back(closeOverlays: true);
      return false;
    },
    child: const QuestionWidget(),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Only add Navigator.pop(Get.overlayContext!, true);

Note: the symbol "!" is only if you're working with nullable type.